# How can I determine the Laplace transform of the following function?

Tags: laplace-transform, integral-transforms

I would like to determine the Laplace transform of the function:  $f(t)=erf^2(t)$

Comment: What have you tried with it?

Comment: I reduced it to  a double integral not involving higher transcendental functions but I can't  uncouple he variables.  A weird bird, not present in the usual tables(Tables of Integral Transforms, McGraw Hill (1955) or the Oberhettinger Badii volume.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is a tough bird. It resisted everything I threw at it.  After several weeks I found an approach that worked.  While it involves only elementary techniques, they are used in an unusual way. It was nonintuitive.

We start with two definitions

$\displaystyle \text{erf}(t)=\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\int_{0}^{t}{e^{-u^2}du}, \quad \text{erfc}(t)=\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\int_{t}^{\infty}{e^{-u^2}du} .\tag*{(A,B)} $

and an easily derived result (complete the square in the exponential):

$ \displaystyle\mathfrak{L}[e^{-at^2}]=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}\;}e^{\frac{p^2}{4a}}\;\text{erfc}\bigg[\frac{p}{2\sqrt{a}}\bigg].  \tag*{(C)}$

Let
$ \displaystyle g(p)=\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-pt}\text{erf}^2(t)dt}.\tag*{(D)}$

An integration by parts gives

$ \displaystyle g(p)=\frac{4}{p\sqrt\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-pt-t^2}\text{erf}(t)dt}\tag*{(E)}$

Let

$\displaystyle G(p)=\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-pt-t^2}\text{erf}(t)dt}\tag*{(F)}$

We will try to find a differential equation satisfied by $G(p)$ .

$\begin{align}\displaystyle -pG(p)+2G’(p)&=\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-pt-t^2}(-p-2t)\text{erf}(t)dt}\\ &=-\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-pt-2t^2}dt}\\ &= -\frac{1}{\sqrt2}e^{\frac{p^2}{8}}\text{erfc}\bigg[\frac{p}{2\sqrt2}\bigg].\end{align}\tag*{(G)}$

The second equation follows by integration by parts, and we then utilized (C). A homogeneous solution of this differential equation is

$\displaystyle H(p)=e^{{p^2}/4}. \tag*{(H)} $

We seek a particular solution $P(p)$ of the form

$ \displaystyle P(p)=\omega(p)H(p).\tag*{(I)} $

We find that

$\displaystyle \omega’(p)=-\frac{1}{2}e^{-{p^2}/8}\text{erfc}\bigg[\frac{p}{2\sqrt2}\bigg].\tag*{(J)}$

But

$ \displaystyle e^{-{p^2}/8}=-\sqrt{(2\pi)}\frac{d}{dp}\text{erfc}\bigg[\frac{p}{2\sqrt 2}\bigg]\tag*{(K)}$

Putting this result in (J) allows us to easily integrate that equation.  We get

$\displaystyle \omega(p)=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{4}\text{erfc}^2\bigg[\frac{p}{2\sqrt2}\bigg].\tag*{(L)} $

Applying the initial value theorem shows that the homogeneous solution cannot appear in the final result.

Putting everything together we have

$\displaystyle g(p)=\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-pt}\text{erf}^2(t)dt}=\frac{e^{{p^2}/4}}{p}\text{erfc}^2\bigg[\frac{p}{2\sqrt2}\bigg].\tag*{(M)}$